# How does SQL Server determine the order of other column not used in order by clause in row_number

Tags: sql-server

I have to generate `row_number` based on a col1, so I use order by on col1, but how the corresponding col2 is ordered, is it always in the same order or different order?

Example below:

```
create table #2 (id int, user_id int, building varchar(10))

insert into #2 (id, user_id, building)
select 1,11,'First'
union all
select 2,13,'First'
union all
select 3,12,'First'
union all
select 4,15,'Second'
union all
select 5, 14,'Second'

select 
    *,
    row_number() over (order by building) 
from #1
```

How is the `user_id` column's order determined?

Comment: Without an explicit order, determined by an `ORDER BY` clause, the order of the rows is as good as random. They will likely return (or in this case "number") in the order that SQL Server "finds" them. What order it finds rows can be effected by a lot of factors, such as the (lack of the) existence of a `CLUSTERED INDEX`, how the data is "arranged" on disc, if the data was split up for processing (by individual cores), and many other factors; even the version and edition can effect it. If you want find out about *how* SQL Server works [DBA](http://dba/stackexchange.com) is the better place.

Comment: On this tiny dataset it will most likely always be the same, but not guaranteed. This is like taking a bucket of coins and wanting them sorted by coin value and date but only specifying the sort order by coin value and expecting the date on the coin to always be sorted. It will not work that way. You MUST provide the order if you want a certain order.

Comment: you can add a second sort to the row_number() over (order by building,user_id). you can also partition by building row_number() over (partition by building order by user_id)

Comment: The short answer is: if you don't specify an order, then SQL Server is free to choose the ordering by whatever criteria it wants, which is usually "what is easiest". This order may even change from run to run, if new rows had been added or some deleted, causing statistics to change, causing the exact SQL Plan generated to change. Never assume what isn't explicit: if there is no specified order, presume the order is random.